# Login Facebook using python

Tags: python, facebook

I m trying this script to login to facebook using python what m I missing ?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass

usr = input('Enter your username or email id: ')
pwd = getpass('Enter your password : ')

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/')

username_box = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
username_box.send_keys(usr)

password_box = driver.find_element_by_id('pass')
password_box.send_keys(pwd)

login_btn = driver.find_element_by_id('u_0_b')
login_btn.submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

'''

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from time import sleep 

usr=input('Enter Email Id:')  
pwd=input('Enter Password:')  

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/') 
print ("Opened facebook") 
sleep(1) 

username_box = driver.find_element_by_id('email') 
username_box.send_keys(usr) 
print ("Email Id entered") 
sleep(1) 

password_box = driver.find_element_by_id('pass') 
password_box.send_keys(pwd) 
print ("Password entered") 

login_box = driver.find_element_by_id('loginbutton') 
login_box.click() 

print ("Done") 
input('Press anything to quit') 
driver.quit() 
print("Finished")
```

'''

Comment: I got this 

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Answer (score 0):

To open chrome, the chrome driver needs to be downloaded and the path should be mentioned here. Download chrome driver according to your chrome version. 
`https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads`
Unzip the file and place it in your local and mention the path in below script.

Code:

`from selenium import webdriver`
`from getpass import getpass`

`usr = input('Enter your username or email id: ')`
`pwd = getpass('Enter your password : ')`

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path_where_chromedriver_with_extension')`
`driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/')`

`username_box = driver.find_element_by_id('email')`
`username_box.send_keys(usr)`

`password_box = driver.find_element_by_id('pass')`
`password_box.send_keys(pwd)`

`login_btn = driver.find_element_by_id('u_0_b')`
`login_btn.submit()`